Circuitikz: change current position in short
Is there a way of changing the position of the arrow for currents or flows in Circuitikz in a short component? For normal components you can use the order of ^ and > to achieve this (the first two lines in my example) but that doesn't work for a short, since this one has no width. I could split the short in two parts and use only one of them for the current annotation, like in the third line, but this expands my code a lot and it's not a nice solution, so can I do this with an option in the first two lines or something like that?
Thank you :)
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,2) to [short,i>^=I] ++ (2,0)
        (0,1) to [short,i^>=I] ++ (2,0)
        (0,0) to [short,i=I] ++ (1,0) -- ++ (1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



This way (a bit hidden in the manual, page 201-202 for the current version)
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,2) to [short,i>^=I] ++ (2,0)
        (0,1) to [short,i^>=I, current/distance=0.2] ++ (2,0)
        (0,0) to [short,i=I] ++ (1,0) -- ++ (1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



Perfect, thank you. Exactly what I was looking for :)
